# android studio install error [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK]

Tags: android

I am getting this:

```
01/20 17:14:40: Launching MyLuaGame $ adb push /Users/name/Desktop/MyLuaGame/frameworks/runtime-src/proj.android-studio/app/build/outputs/apk/MyLuaGame-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/myTest 
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/myTest" Please select on your phone whether can install the app by The ADB command?
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/myTest Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK]
$ adb shell pm uninstall myTest DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR 

Error while Installing APK
```

Comment: What is your question ? What did you try ? In which context do you have this error?

Comment: Is a package with this name already installed?

Answer (score 2):

You have to execute a release apk for installation in device. You can connect your device in android studio and get the debug version app but in order to get an apk to install other devices, you must execute release version apk using a keystore

Answer (score 1):

A common reason for this error is having an app with the same package name already installed but with a different certificate e.g. a store release or a development build from another machine.

Try uninstalling the package with ADB first, using `adb uninstall YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME`